# How to connect ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor pages with MySql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core razor pages website since I'm a beginner. I'm trying to connect my web application with MySql database. Since I'm a beginner I don't really know how to connect my application with MySql database. I know how to connect with SQL Server, but I want to know about connecting to MySql.

A complete working process with MySql and Asp.Net core 2.2 Razor pages would be much appreciated.

Comment: Download package connector via nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/.. and then RTFM config section https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/overview/configuration/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [Setup Entity Framework Core for MySQL in ASP.NET Core 2](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/setup-entity-framework-core-for-mysql-in-asp-net-core-2-5b40a5a3af94), as it covers the basics on how to use **MySQL** with **ASP.Net Core 2**.

Just make sure you also take a look at [MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore), Oracle's official package for **.Net Core**, instead of using **Pomelo's** (used it in the past, but if there's an official one, it worth a check).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Neither `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` or `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` support .NET Core 2.2 at this time.  OP should probably revert to .NET Core 2.1 until MySQL providers release new versions.

Comment: Or grab the GIt repositories (if open source) and compile/create nuget packages on his own until they become available