# How to use MySql.Data refrence in dotnet core 2.2 Version

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am using dotnet core 2.2 , when I am trying to add MySql.data dll reference it is showing restore the project, and not supporting the version even I had tried all the MySql versions in my project.

The exact error is:
 **"error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'MySql.Data (>= 8.0.16)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'."**

all versions of Mysql.data I had tried
**It is also showing :**
[image: Screen shot when i am trying to add the package]

Comment: the same error is resolved here : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/159780/error-nu1100-unable-to-resolve-netstandardlibrary.html 
 or https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/977

Comment: In the above link, the issue is different that is related to NETStandard.Library, mine issue is related to MySql.data library.

Comment: Look at my previous answer @AbhayAgarwal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837510/how-to-migrate-my-tables-from-my-asp-net-core-app-on-linux/56843073#56843073

Answer (score 0):

searching this issue and found that you can not add dll, but you must add from nuget package.

> 1. Go to Application ->right click on project name-> select Manage Nuget
>      Packages-> Type MySql .Data
> 2. Go to Project root-> appsettings.json-> enter the connection string, as shown below.

Just refer this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-connect-mysql-with-asp-net-core/)

From this step project check the proper mysql dll based on compatibility.

You are not written about mysql connect with entity : if you wish to add that then just refer below link too.

[How to connect ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor pages with MySql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901397/how-to-connect-asp-net-core-2-2-razor-pages-with-mysql-database)

Comment: from Nuget i had tried to add MySql.Data package but same thing happning,I had update the qus , now it is much clear

Comment: are you check the 1st link, just try step by step with new project and check is that working?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `dotnet add package MySqlConnector`

[MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net) is an alternative OSS MySQL library for .NET that supports `netcoreapp2.1` and `netcoreapp2.2`, as well as the latest ADO.NET APIs being added by Microsoft.